# how to make a circle hover on an image

Tags: jquery, css, hover

```
.ec-circle{
width: 420px;
height: 420px;
-webkit-border-radius: 210px;
-moz-border-radius: 210px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
font-family:'Kelly Slab', Georgia, serif;
background: #dda994 url(../images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
box-shadow:
    inset 0 0 1px 230px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    inset 0 0 0 7px #d5ad94;
transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
display: block;
outline: none;
}
```

above code is like what i want but not fulfill my need.

### i want circle hover on my image.

it is the image of resolution 230 x 231. when hover on image,
it will shown only circle part.

how it will be?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change the border radius of image on hover

```
img:hover{border-radius:50%}
```

#### Sidenote

Instead of calculating half of image size and give it to the image border radius value just give `50%` to it!

[Check the demo out here](http://jsbin.com/iyutig)

Answer (score 1):

You say the size of your image is around 230px square, but your circle class is of 420px square. I think if I understand your question, you should use a width and height of the circle that's smaller than the size of your image.

About the hover, firstly, I notice that you are using the image as a background, so I assume that the css class you have is for a div. But there is no `:hover` pseudo-class for divs, so you can't do the hover directly with css. If you want to change the style of one object on an event on another, you must use js.

Comment: [link](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverClickTriggerCircle/) this is a link. but i want my full background image when not hovered. and when hovered, show only circled image.